# Espresso :Nullpointer Exception on Button performClick

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-espresso

I am trying to write UI Tests for my app using Espresso for my compose elements.
I have a initial introductory screen with a sign in button at the bottom.

Onclick of sign in button, the page should navigate to Login page.

Below is my code for Introductory screen which has below sign button:

```
@Composable
fun IntroductorySignInButton(navController: NavController) {
    Button(
        onClick = {
            navController.navigate(Screen.LoginScreen.route) {
                popUpTo(Screen.WelcomeScreen1.route) { inclusive = true }
            }
        },
        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
            backgroundColor = Blue5,
            contentColor = White
        ),
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(start = 32.dp, end = 32.dp, bottom = 34.dp)
            .semantics { testTag = "SignIn Button" }
    ) {
        Text(
            text = stringResource(id = R.string.signin_button_text),
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.button
        )
    }
}
```

Using espresso, I tried to assert if the signin button exist and performed click but giving NPE

Below is the test code:

```
@Test
    fun sign_in_btn_exist(){
        composeTestRule.setContent {
            IntroductorySignInButton(navController = rememberNavController())
        }
        composeTestRule.onNodeWithTag("SignIn Button").assertExists()
        composeTestRule.onNodeWithTag("SignIn Button").assertExists().assert(hasText("SIGN IN"))
        composeTestRule.onNodeWithTag("SignIn Button").performClick()

    }
```

The test shows the sign in button exists but when performClick , it's giving NPE.